# Finding two patterns in a line and remove the patterns and sequence between them

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with lines like this:

```
ABCDABCBCBBBCBCDDBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
ABCDCCCBCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
ABCDACDCDCCCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
```

And I want

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
```

So the goal is to remove everything starting with the `ABCD` up to, and including, the first occurence of 4 consecutive `B`s. It is guaranteed that all lines start with `ABCD` and that there can be no "stray" `BBBB` on the line before the "relevant" chain of `B`s that precedes the closing `XYZ`.

I have tried variations of `sed` with this one getting close:

```
sed 's/ABCD.*BBBB//g' filename
```

Which gives me `XYZ`, I think because it doesn't stop until the last `BBBB` pattern, but I want it to stop after the first one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your `sed` approach fails is - as you suspected - that `sed` works on the basis of regular expressions, and these are "greedy", i.e. they try to match the longest possible string they can describe.

So, this might be a task for `awk`. Consider this program:

```
awk '{n=index($0,"BBBB"); print substr($0,n+4)}' input.txt
```

This will locate the first occurence of the substring `BBBB` in the current line (denoted by `$0`) and store the position in `n`. It will then print the part of the line starting at this position plus 4 (to remove the initial 4 `B`s) up to the end of the line.

Note that there is no mention of the starting pattern `ABCD` here because your example input indicates *all* lines start with `ABCD`, in which case it is sufficient to remove everything from the start of the line up to, and including, the first 4-`B`-pattern. It will not work as expected if the assumption is incorrect, in particular if `BBBB` can occur before `ABCD`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one occurrence of a `BBBB*` sequence, you can tell `sed` to only remove the first `BBBB` that is preceded by **another** character.

```
sed 's/^ABCD.*[^B]BBBB//'
```

If the `BBBB` sequence starts only once every line, that should do the job.

Note that it will not work with a strings like:

```
ABCDEBBBBBFBBBBBXYZ
```

because that are two occurrences of `BBBB` that is preceded by non-B, and the greedy algorithm will catch the second once as well.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you **asked** for (`remove everything starting with the ABCD up to, and including, the first occurence of 4 consecutive Bs.`) with any awk would be:

```
$ awk -v beg='ABCD' -v end='BBBB' '
    { gsub(end,"\n") }
    match($0,beg"[^\n]+\n") { $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }
    { gsub(/\n/,end) }
1' file
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
```

That works whether ABCD is first in the line or BBBB can appear before it, etc.:

```
$ echo 'xyz BBBB foo ABCD bar BBBB etc BBBB anon' |
    awk -v beg='ABCD' -v end='BBBB' '{gsub(end,"\n")} match($0,beg"[^\n]+\n"){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} {gsub(/\n/,end)} 1'
xyz BBBB foo  etc BBBB anon
```

Answer (score 1):

The task can be broken down into two stages. We put a mark and then delete:

```
sed '/ABC/s/B\{4\}/&\n/;s/ABC.*\n//' file
```

`\n` - mark

To avoid false cases when the `BBBB` template is in front of the `ABC` template, you can add another command that will remove the false mark:

```
sed 's/B\{4\}/&\n/;s/ABC.*\n//;s/\n//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -pe 's/^^ ABCD .*? B**4 //;'
```

Sample Input:

```
ABCDABCBCBBBCBCDDBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
ABCDCCCBCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
ABCDACDCDCCCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
```

Sample Output:

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku includes a sophisticated update to the well-regarded PCRE engine. Still, the code above uses the familiar `s///` operator in conjunction with the `-pe` (auto-printing, linewise) flags.

For the problem as stated, the solution is as simple as converting the "greedy" `.*` regex to a "frugal" `.*?` regex. Just the inclusion of the `?` is enough for Raku to know to stop at the appropriate spot nearest the *left*-end of the consecutive-`B` run (the `B**4` regex tells Raku to search for 4-consecutive `B`s).

That's the simplest solution. However, if some help is needed in visualizing what's getting deleted, just flip over to the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flag(s), in conjunction with either the `S///` (non-destructive substitution) or `m/…/` (match) operators:

```perl
$ raku -pe 's/^^ ABCD .*? B**4 //;' file
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
$ raku -ne 'put S/^^ ABCD .*? B**4 //;' file
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
$ raku -ne 'put s/^^ ABCD .*? B**4 //;' file
ABCDABCBCBBBCBCDDBBBB
ABCDCCCBCCBBBB
ABCDACDCDCCCCBBBB
$ raku -ne 'm/^^ ABCD .*? B**4 /.put;' file
ABCDABCBCBBBCBCDDBBBB
ABCDCCCBCCBBBB
ABCDACDCDCCCCBBBB
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sed`'s regular expressions are "greedy" (i.e. they try to match as much as possible).   `sed` doesn't have a non-greedy quantifier for matches, but `perl` does - just append `?` after whatever you're trying to match.  e.g.

```
$ sed 's/ABCD.*BBBB//g' input.txt 
XYZ
XYZ
XYZ
$ perl -p -e 's/ABCD.*?BBBB//g' input.txt 
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBXYZ
```

BTW, most simple `sed` scripts like yours can be run with `perl -p -e` instead of `sed` (or `perl -n -e` with `print` statements where appropriate, instead of `sed -n` with `p` commands) - but using perl regular expressions rather than [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) (sed's default) or ERE (`sed -E`).   Note that, unlike `sed`, the `-e` to indicate that the next arg is a script is not optional for `perl`.

From `man perlre`:

> By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will match as
> many times as possible (given a particular starting location) while still
> allowing the rest of the pattern to match.  If you want it to match the
> minimum number of times possible, follow the quantifier with a `?`. Note that
> the meanings don't change, just the "greediness":
>
> ```
> *?        Match 0 or more times, not greedily
> +?        Match 1 or more times, not greedily
> ??        Match 0 or 1 time, not greedily
> {n}?      Match exactly n times, not greedily (redundant)
> {n,}?     Match at least n times, not greedily
> {n,m}?    Match at least n but not more than m times, not greedily
> ```